# Is there a way to keep the heads-up notification banner showing? Or specify the amount of time it should stay before it goes away?

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging, notification-channel

Is there a way to make stay longer, stick until the user clicks it, or specify time for it to stay there before hiding ?
I am using Firebase Cloud Messaging.

How does Whatsapp manage to do this for incoming calls ?

[image]

Comment: This might help you https://medium.com/android-news/full-screen-intent-notifications-android-85ea2f5b5dc1

Answer (score -1):

That can be difficult, from what I've read, keeping a heads-up notification comes from a high priority alert:
https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/time-sensitive#create-high-priority-notification

You may be able to get the same results from FCM with a high priority message, just know that this does have varied results on user devices from settings to custom lock screens.

source:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#setting-the-priority-of-a-message